# SSRS Report Multiple Pages Tablix Order

Tags: reporting-services, rdl

I'm using ReportingService 2010 and im trying to get multiple reports into one file on sperate pages. The problem is the order of the pages.

At this point I have a table for each of my datasets on seperate pages. Export to Excel works great, but the order of the pages (Web View and Excel Worksheets) doesn't match the order of my Tablix elements of the rdl file.

Setup is like:

```
    ..
<DataSets>
    Dataset Name="A"
    Dataset Name="B"
    Dataset Name="C"
</DataSets>
    ..
<ReportItems> 
    <Tablix Name="A_Tablix">...<PageBreak><BreakLocation>End</BreakLocation></PageBreak></Tablix>
    <Tablix Name="B_Tablix">...<PageBreak><BreakLocation>End</BreakLocation></PageBreak></Tablix>
    <Tablix Name="C_Tablix">...<PageBreak><BreakLocation>End</BreakLocation></PageBreak></Tablix>
</ReportItems> 
...
```

But the pages seem to appear like random, and not in the order of the rdl file. Is there any element I'm missing? Or how do I have to order the Tablix elements of the code to get the same order in the Web View and Excel Worksheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, after some experimentation...

The problem was, that the Tablix were overlapping. They started at `Top 0` and `Left 0`. It works as expected, after I added an offset according to the desired position to the `Top` value like:
x*Height of Tablix

Comment: You are a lifesaver! My first Tablix was 2.7cm tall and my second one for some reason started at `2.69959` and I could not for the life of me work out why they were coming out on top of each other.